# Смартфон в windows8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, iphone

Хочу создать десктопное wpf приложение для windows 8 на ПК, которым можно будет управлятьс помочью смартфона. Возможно ли это как то реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте клиенты приложения для смартфонов и организуйте связь через WCF